# Android add a layout programmatically?

Tags: android

I have another class other than my main class, and inside this I want to add a layout programmatically with:

```
myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
```

But it crashes the app, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the layout params for the app. Right now your relative layout has no width or height.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new 
        LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
myLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

This should work. if it doesnt put your stacktrace.

Comment: Doesnt work. Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) 
 ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1815 
 ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1831 
 ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 122 
 ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1024 
 Activity...ain(String[]) line: not available [native method]